# NodeJs: not returning correct count fo Dynamodb table

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have the following code:

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-eas-1'});
var ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB({region: 'us-east-1'});

async function countData(){
     var params ={TableName: 'tbl_billings_trns'}
     const countdb1 =  await ddb.describeTable(params).promise();
     console.log(countdb1);
    console.log("Total count " + numbers.toString());
     return numbers;
      
  }

countData()
```

I also tried:

```
async function kk(){
var jj = await countData();
console.log(jj);
}

kk()
```

It is giving count 0, but Table has 12 items.

I used await after promisify it, but unable to achieve it. Any help will be great for me.

Comment: Where does `numbers` come from? Where do you attempt to get a count from `countdb1`?

Comment: 1. It comes from the table  but table already has 12 items 2. in lambda inside async default method of index.handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the `DescribeTable` API-call to get the count of items.

This is actually not a live-count as per the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_TableDescription.html#DDB-Type-TableDescription-ItemCount):

> **ItemCount**
>
> The number of items in the specified table. DynamoDB updates this value approximately every six hours. Recent changes might not be reflected in this value.

The data you're receiving may be up to 6 hours old, which is probably why it doesn't match.

To get a more accurate number you'd have to scan through the table, which is very expensive and you really should avoid.

Comment: Thank you Maurice for your valuable reply it made me crazy ...async await is working for all other SDK api methods but not for this

Comment: Been there, done that ;-) - Rule of thumb: Any value you get from the API that would be expensive to retrieve at scale is probably not live.

Comment: Yes actually on depending that value I want to invoke another lambda if itemcount greater than 0 now do not know how would I do that in node js lambda

Comment: If that's the case, you can do a scan with a limit of 1, which is still fairly cheap.

Answer (score 0):

If your application needs to fetch more accurate aggregations, you might consider maintaining the count yourself in DynamoDB.  For example, if you need to keep a count of Users/Products/Orders/etc, you could maintain a summary record that gets incremented/decremented as you add/remove items from the table.  This is especially useful if your application has a reporting mechanism that requires aggregates that would otherwise only be available via an expensive scan operation.

A common pattern to maintain your own summary records is to use DynamoDB streams.  When your lambda gets a notification of a new or deleted item, you could update the summary records accordingly.